# How to use Content Type: aplication/json ,with request+restfulapi on node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, content-type

how to understand the concept of content type aplication/json, if i have restful api module, and a request on node server

```
var request = require('request');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
request({
  url: 'http://localhost/4000/notes/12vdsgte5657',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {mes_id: '12vdsgte5657'}
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

and this on API router

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
  app.get('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
      //const id = req.params.id;
      console.log(req.body,id)
      console.log(req.params.id,new ObjectID(id))
      const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
      db.collection('notes').findOne(details, (err, item) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
          res.send(item);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

how can i use json data to my API module, i can understand the concept if it parse parameter on body or in the url, but when in JSON i can't, what is that for what is deferent why must i use JSON, what is the concept for it

I use json: {mes_id: '12vdsgte5657'}, and I can't console it, req.param for get data from url, req.body to get data from body, from json? req.json?
what is the magic to console the json from the server, or I miss the concept

---

#### Solved

now I find the answer, you can past json like that but you required app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: What's a "consep"?

Comment: how it work and how to use

Comment: i use json: {mes: 'heydude'}, and i cant console it, req.param for get data from url, req.body to get data from body, from json? req.json? what is the magic to console the json from the server

Comment: @Frog I didn't get you question well, But it seems that you don't use `app.use(bodyParser.json());` in your server.js file. it will parse your data in to json type.

Comment: i already use it but, i still cant console my  json: {mes: 'heydude'}, what is the trick to console it or use it req.body return {}, req.json return undefined

Comment: @Viran Malaka, yes i need `app.use(bodyParser.json())`, then i can `console.log(req.body) //{mes_id: '12vdsgte5657'}`